# How to make polygon in svg responsive (vw, vh)

Tags: svg, charts, graphics

I'm starting to learn svg.
And I found out that coordinates x y, as well as svg sizes, can be specified in vw vh. But when I write   `<polygon points="2vw,1vw 1vw, 9vw 4vw, 3vw, 2vw" fill="red"/>` for example.

This is not working. Can i make polygons in vw?? or do polygons have some alternatives?

Comment: units are not allowed. use a viewBox to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Please try this instead: `<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10"><polygon points="2,1 1,9 4,3" fill="red"/></svg>` Observe that the svg element has a viewBox and no width and/or height. This way will take all the width available. Also make sure that the polygon's points attribute has an even number of values (one for x ant the second one for y). In your example the last 2 (for x) has no y value